# How was Margaret not going to get deported for marrying Andrew?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, the-proposal

In the movie, *The Proposal*, how was Margaret not going to get deported for marrying Andrew? I don't know much about immigration and deportation and the bunch so any more insight would help me understand what was happening in the movie would be lovely.

Comment: The premise of the movie revolves around the concept that: A legitimate marriage to a US citizen is grounds for granting US citizenship to the foreign national who is not doing anything illegal.  Of course, Sandra Bullock's character (Margaret) is not initially attempting to make a legitimate marriage, and that makes for the drama and comedy in the movie.

Comment: @John You should post as answer

Answer (score 1):

By marrying Andrew she can stay in the US because having a husband who is a US citizen, it can give you certain rights to stay in that country.